# Copy to clipboard BINARY data in browsers

Tags: javascript, flash, coffeescript, clipboard

## State of the art in Copy to Clipboard feature (My investigations)

### Flash alternative

- I have found the following alternatives:

  - Zclip: we are using
  - zeroclipboard (ancestor, zclip uses its button flash movie): only text
  - Clippy: only text in the page https://github.com/mojombo/clippy
- You can see in the (ActionScript:Flash) code: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/source/browse/trunk/ZeroClipboard.as (line 77)
- They use System.setClipboard(cliptText) call, which only supports plain text strings, as we can see in Adobe AIR API refference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/system/System.html
- So we cant pass formatted text through flash.

### HTML5 alternative

There is an API in draft to standardize clipboard events, but is not implemented in any browser for the moment http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/

## My Rails/Zclip implementation

I'm using zclip (based on zeroclipboard) to copy text from a restfule service to the system clipboard:

```
$('.copy-to-clipboard').zclip
  path:'/ZeroClipboard.swf'
  setHandCursor: true
  copy: -> 
    ajaxReturn = $.ajax
     type: 'GET'
     async: false
     url: '/resources/copy_to_clipboard/' + $(this).attr("class").match(/[0-9]+/)
    return ajaxReturn.responseText
```

It's coffeescript.

If the service (/resources/copy_to_clipboard/) serves text it's copied right. But if it servers a DOCX file, it doesn't copy right to the clipboard. Take a look at the rails controller:

```
  def copy_to_clipboard
    send_file @resource.resource_content.content.file.file, :type => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
  end
```

## The question

Have you solved the copy BINARY data to clipboard any time ? and how ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: the clipboard JS API is now [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard) quite well among the top browsers. But I don't know it this could help with binary data copying.

Comment: Perhaps you might consider the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5416795/1544012) that allows to drag & drop files from the server to the desktop? It is said to work only in chrome though.

Comment: My goal is to put a ZIP blob with data flavor 'GVML', with the end goal of copy/pasting charts from browser to Office as editable objects.

Comment: Wouldn't letting web pages copy binary data be a possible security issue as the uses would not know the contents?

Comment: I don't think binary is possible. The native solution BoraMa suggested is for text. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33928558/266535) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I read [Clipboard API and events](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/) and write following code and that works for me.The only issue is working with `NULL (0x0)` value.Way of using code is setting `x` array with your desired binary values and call `document.execCommand('copy')` function,congratulation your data is in clipboard!

```js
var x = [0x1b, 0x68, 101, 108, 108, 0x6f, 0x7, 0x8];
var button = document.getElementById("copy-button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.execCommand('copy');
}, false);

document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  var str = '';
  x.forEach(function(d) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(d)
  })
  //You can ignore setting third parameter value
  e.clipboardData.setData('text', str, true);
  console.info('data copied');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="copy-button">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

And here is paste result in Notepad++ with `Show All Characters` menu item on:
[image]
I hope this helps ;)