# Drag file from browser to desktop that requires premission

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, drag-and-drop

While it seems to be possible to drag a file from a browser to the desktop as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416748/4553162), it doesn't seem to work for files on Amazon S3 that require credentials that are passed as query string parameters. The url of the file I am trying to copy is in this format:

```
https://my-domain.amazonaws.com/uploads/mypath/myfile.txt?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Date=20180924T195935Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=mycredential&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=mysig
```

If I change the permissions on the file in S3 to be public and change the path to be:

```
https://my-domain.amazonaws.com/uploads/mypath/myfile.txt
```

all works correctly.

I am binding to the `dragstart` event and setting the download url as follows:

```
evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "https://my-domain.amazonaws.com/uploads/mypath/myfile.txt?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Date=20180924T195935Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=mycredential&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=mysig");
```

Is there any way make the file download with the credentials passed?