# Add dropped file to a file input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, file-io

I have a custom file input:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span id="fake-text-input"></span>
    <button id="select-a-file"></button>
    <input id="hidden-file-input" type="file" />
</div>
```

The `input[type="file"]` is hidden (`display: none`) and selecting a file is handled by listening\triggering the `click` and `change` events.

I want to support file drop as well. I was able to listen to the `drop` event when a file is dropped on `#fake-text-input` but I don't know how to forward the `drop` event to the `input[type="file"]`.. is it even possible?

I'm not interested in file input opacity tricks :)

```
$('body').on('drop', '#wrapper', function(e) {
    var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];

    // I have the file.. now what?
});
```

Comment: can you provide your code of what you have tried ?

Comment: You should take a look at this SOq. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input

Comment: @insomiac look at my edit. There's not much code though..

Comment: @cggaurav so that means it can't be done?

Comment: I don't know any possibility to append files to the file input. I think it's not allowed for security reasons. But maybe you don't need it. Why can't you just fire POST request using $.ajax({type: "POST", ...}) immediately after you got a file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is worked with me in google chrome , the problem now with other browsers

```
$("input[type='file']").prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
```

Comment: well, let me know if you find a solution

Comment: @nassimPHP, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

From @NassimPHP 's answer, this worked!

```
$("input[type='file']").prop("files", e.dataTransfer.files);
```