# Create a FileList and copy it to a File input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi

I'm trying to create a drag and drop area that will get dataTransfer items by *webkitGetAsEntry* and check if the entry is a directory or file.

I then would like to be able to make the files into a FileList and copy that to a file input (that will be validated and proccesed before posted).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg2st/1/)

```
  function handleDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        var length = event.dataTransfer.items.length;
        var elFileInput = document.getElementById('File');
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var entry = event.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if (entry.isFile) {
                convertFilesToFileObjects(entry);          
            } 
            else if (entry.isDirectory) {
                var dirReader = entry.createReader();
                dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                        convertFileEntrysToFileObjects(entries[j]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }   
        function convertFileEntrysToFileObjects(fileEntry) {        
            var addFileToInput = function (file) {
                console.log(file);
                //elFileInput.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
                //Need to make a FileList and populate it with Files.
            };       
            if (fileEntry.isFile) {
                fileEntry.file(function (addFileToInput, file) {
                    addFileToInput(file);
                }.bind(this, addFileToInput));
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot copy a file to the FileList in the HTMLInputElement it's readonly [W3 FileList Interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filelist)

I'm stuck at trying to make a FileList object by using prototypes and extending objects, I haven't quite wrapped my head around JS inheritance and prototypes yet.

I's it even possible to make a FileList object and populate it with files, then copy it to the InputElement?

Edited: Wrong JSFiddle link.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input It seems possible these days, but only with a real `FileList` and you can't seem to make those...

Answer (score -4):

Why do you need to copy a file to FileList?

Use FileReader instead. But validate a file before send is not a good idea. For security, you should do this in server side. You can validate the file before, but you SHOULD validate the file again when received.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader

Comment: I'm doing both client and server-side validation on the HtmlInputElement using Annotations in MVC3. The form get posted as HttpPostedFileBase Class and handled in the Controller. I'm thinking of using a FileRead instead and post the files using XMLHttpRequest, but if I could get this to work I'd be happy.