# Get dropped file as input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I handle the file entered in an input type "file" so:

`<input id="upload_button" type="file"/>`

And then:

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {                                  

        var target = evt.dataTransfer || evt.target;
        var file = target && target.files && target.files[0];
        (...)
    };
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#upload_button')).on('change', handleFileSelect);`
```

As you can see `document.querySelector('#upload_button').on('change', handleFileSelect);`.

But I would like to do the same with a drag & drop div:

```
<div class="drop-zone" id="upload_drop" >
        <img src="../images/icon_cloud.png"/>
        <font class="receipt_upload_font"> Beleg per Drag & Drop hinzufügen</font>
        <font class="receipt_upload_oder_font"> oder unten "Beleg hinzufügen" klicken und Datei auswählen</font>
    </div>`
```

But I don't know how to do it. :( I can't handle the dropped file in the div as the input.

Comment: reduce your code to only what is required to understand your problem, there's way too much here, I don't want to read your entire method.  Please do a search before posting a new question.  Possible duplicate of [drag drop files into standard html file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input)

Comment: I think that's what you need : https://jqueryui.com/droppable/. You need the jqui API for that though

Comment: As a suggestion, don't use `<font>` tag, it is from stone age.

Comment: @davidcondrey this [drag drop files into standard html file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input) doesn't work for me, 'cause there I shall have the input tag inside the div where I'll drop. => `<div><input></div>` but I need to use it so: `<div id="drop-zone"></div><div id="another-div"></div><input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a best way to do it.

While drop, I used instead:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#upload_button')).on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

this one:

```
<div class="drop-zone" id="upload_drop" >
    <img src="../images/icon_cloud.png"/>
    <font class="receipt_upload_font"> Beleg per Drag & Drop hinzufügen</font>
    <font class="receipt_upload_oder_font"> oder unten "Beleg hinzufügen" klicken und Datei auswählen</font>
</div>
<script>
 var dropZone = document.getElementById('upload_drop');

    // Get file data on drop
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
        handleFileSelect(e);
    });
<script>
```

So it works when I drop something.