# html5 drag file to input - can I drag multiple times into same input and have file added instead of replacing?

Tags: javascript, html

The following is a snippet to drag and drop files into a file input and also has a button. Is there any way that I can make it so I can drag or click to add a single (or any number of files) multiples times, but instead of replacing the file already there it just adds to them?

```
dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
};

dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
  // pretty simple -- but not for IE :(
  fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  evt.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="dropContainer" style="border:1px solid black;height:100px;">
   Drop Here
</div>
  Should update here:
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears that it is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: that isn't what I was trying to do, I figured it out and posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it. I originally had 10 inputs, with the last 9 hidden on the page and a function called showNext to unhide the next input row. the important part is I changed a line in .ondrop to add the file data to a particular input by its index and then unhide the next input.

```
 dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
  var fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName('fileInput');

  // pretty simple -- but not for IE :(
  fileInput[].files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  evt.preventDefault();
    count = count + 1;
  showNext(count);
};
```

Comment: Can you attach more of your code? I think I need to see your html and showNext method to get a better understanding. I'm trying to multiple files also.