# Drag-Drop that affects an input file element in Angular (2+)

Tags: angular, file, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am a student.

-Is there a way to fill the file input with the right filename from a file drop? I've already read all the answers at [drag drop files into standard html file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input)

However, no answer there works for Angular 4. I guess there is always a problem with Typescript I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by either creating a fileupload `directive` or use existing `modules` on `npm`. i would recommend use a existing module because it would be well tested already. and you can easily import it in your solution

here are some references to the modules on npm

[ngx-file-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop)

[ng4-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-files-upload)

also here is a tutorial how create a file drop directive .
[Drag and Drop file directive in angular2](https://scotch.io/@minrock/how-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-file-directive-in-angular2-with-angular-cli-part-2)