# Upload an image using drag & drop over a placeholder image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, drag-and-drop

I have been tying to work it out since last couple of days... and finally hope i would get some answers from the lavarel community.

While working my Laravel project where I am trying to upload an image (single image) using either drag & drop or  select.

NOTE: I have a placeholder image which i want to use it as a dropzone, and also the size may vary depending on where i want to use. Now I should be able to drop an image on this placeholder image.
On drop or select the new image replaces the placeholder image (this part i am able to achieve) but when i am trying to submit the form if I have drop a file it won't get to the controller. But when i select the file i am good.

Here is what i have done so far... Can any one let me know what is wrong with the drag & drop method for submitting... the only issue i can think of is the <input type="file"> is not able to set the value when when file is dropped.

Here is my blade form

```
<form class="form" action="{{ route('categories.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="category" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Category</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input id="category" type="text" class="form-control @error('category') is-invalid @enderror" name="category" value="{{ old('category') }}">
                            @error('category')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="slug" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Slug</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input id="slug" type="text" class="form-control @error('slug') is-invalid @enderror" name="slug" value="{{ old('slug') }}">
                            @error('slug')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="order" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Display Order</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input id="order" type="number" class="form-control" name="order" value="{{ old('order') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="status" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Status</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select id="status" class="form-control form__select" name="status">
                                <option value="1">Active</option>
                                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="file" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Upload Image</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="upload-area" id="uploadfile">
                                {{-- <h1>Drag and Drop file here<br/>Or<br/>Click to select file</h1> --}}
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/640x480.png') }}" height="200px" id="file_preview" alt="img" />
                            </div>
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                            @error('file')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="form__submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

style.css

```
.upload-area{
    width: 42%;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

.upload-area:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-area h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: darkslategray;
}

#file{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and finally my JavaScript

```
 // On File Drop
        $('.upload-area').on('drop', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass("dragover");
   
            var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
            readFile(file);

            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file[0]);
            // uploadData(fd);
        });

        // Open file selector on div click
        $("#uploadfile").click(function () {
            $("#file").click();
        });

        // file selected
        $("#file").change(function () {
            var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
            readFile(file);
        });


    function readFile(file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#file_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006715/drag-drop-files-into-standard-html-file-input Try the way the answer here does it

Comment: using `new DataTransfer();`

Comment: also, you may still need to preventDefault on drag over, `dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
};` -- you have to do that if you're not doing jquery, not sure if you're doing that here. Are you sure your `readFile` function is even being hit after dropping? I'd double check that

Comment: Thanks @TKoL, this was the missing piece 
$('.upload-area').on('drop', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("dragover");

    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

    if (files && files.length) {

        // we set our input's 'files' property
        $('#file')[0].files = files;

    }
    readFile(files[0]);
});