# Storing file chooser data in a hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, tampermonkey

I am using a tool called TamperMonkey to modify a webpage for my personal convenience. TamperMonkey lets you modify the client-side HTML etc. by appending JavaScript to the page after it loads.

The webpage has a file chooser, but it doesn't let you drag-and-drop a file. I use this webpage a lot so having drag-and-drop functionality would really help.

This page has a form with a file input type.  I've been reading, and there's no way to modify a file input type for security reasons. But, using TamperMonkey, I could change the input type of the file chooser to "hidden," then set the hidden input value to the file contents that I drop on the webpage, right? It's my understanding that the server couldn't tell the difference (if the `name` attribute is the same).

**I don't know how to set the hidden input type to the same data the file chooser would have**:

I've got my file here: `const file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];`

I've got my hidden input type by doing this: `const hiddenField = $("iframe").contents().find(".file-input").attr('type','hidden')`

I just don't know how to take `file` and set it on `hiddenField`. Should this value be base64 encoded? A blob?  Regardless, what code would set the data correctly?

The form it's wrapped in looks like this:

```
<form ... method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Important context for alternative suggestions: this file chooser input isn't on the page at all until you click a button. Then it shows up in an iframe.

I am using firefox.

Comment: Are you able to share more code? or even the url for the website?

Comment: @Goldwave I can't share the website. I can share code if you tell me what more you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried dragging the file onto the select button? the "Select file to upload" button. Or is there no such thing?

Comment: @Goldwave it doesn't work.  The select button is in a pop-up and I have to click something before it shows up.

Comment: Some ideas. 1) In dragover event on document.body change the style of the existing file input so it covers the entire page e.g. add a humongous transparent border and use absolute positioning + z-index 2) replace the submit event of the page and construct the payload yourself using FormData API which can directly use a file blob that you would read from the file's contents in your `drop` event handler.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I'm asking how to do #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to modify a file input type with Tampermonkey.

If you are not able to [add drag and drop support to the input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968948/1273830) itself straight away, you can implement drag and drop using another dom element and use them as below.

```
const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || // Firefox < 62 workaround exploiting https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422655
new DataTransfer(); // specs compliant (as of March 2018 only Chrome)

dT.items.add(new File([dataURItoBlob(image)], '1.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' }));
dT.items.add(new File([dataURItoBlob(image2)], '2.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' }));

// then ...
// $("iframe").contents().find(".file-input").get(0).files = dT.files;
```

[That snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/1273830) was tested working, in a similar setting where a file input was being attached to the page dynamically after clicking a button. The images were drag n dropped onto the page using a different div.

Comment: I already have the file: `const file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]; ` I'm going to attempt to use the last line of your answer.

Comment: Would be nice to link to [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119426/how-to-set-file-objects-and-length-property-at-filelist-object-where-the-files-a/47172409#47172409) you pick half of your code...